# RIA Services matching a response to the request

Tags: wcf-ria-services, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I was wondering if someone could provide some advice on the following problem. We are currently developing a Silverlight 4 application based on RIA .NET Services. One of the screens in the application allows users to type in a search string and after 2 seconds of inactivity the request is submitted to our domain service. This is all handles nicely with Rx.

Now currently it is possible for a second search to be executed before the original has returned. Its also possible that the second request could return before the first.

Really I'm just trying to find out what patterns and approaches people are using to manage the correct response to the correct request.

Are you using some sort of operation identifier in your requests? 
Are you creating new instances of your domain services for each request? 
Is there away to tie the completed event of a request to the Rx observable monitoring the textchange event?

Any steer would be helpful really,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

It should be quite easy for you to solve this problem.

If I assume you have an observable of string that initiates the search and that you have a domain service that returns a `Result` object when given the string then this is the kind of code you need:

```
IObservable<string> searchText
    = ...;

Func<string, IObservable<Result>> searchRequest
    = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, Result>(
        search.BeginInvoke,
        search.EndInvoke);

IObservable<Result> results
    = (from st in searchText
       select searchRequest(st))
      .Switch();
```

The magic is in the `Switch` extension method which "switches" to the latest observable returned from the `IObservable<IObservable<Result>>` - yes, it is a nested observable.

When a new `searchText` comes in, the query returns a new `IObservable<Result>` created from the incoming search text. The `Switch` then switches the `results` observable to use this latest observable and just ignores any previously created observables.

So the result is that only the latest search results are observed and any previous results are ignored.

Hopefully that makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Erik Meijer addresses this here (after about 30 minutes): http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/FTL01
He explains the Switch statement after about 36 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The simples way IMO is to have a subject for requests that you notify before any request is dispatched to WCF. Then rather than subscribing to observable created from the completed event subscribe to `CompletedEventObservable.TakeUntil(RequestsSubject)`. This way you will never be notified with the response to the previous request.

Answer (score 0):

Check out rxx http://rxx.codeplex.com/

It has tons of extra stuff that will help, particularly in your case, I think Dynamic Objects and observable object props might be something that will make your life easier.